# Finish Current Activity Immediately

Tags: android, xamarin, lifecycle

Right now, I have an activity with method PrepareData(), used to prepare every data that needed by current activity, this called in OnCreate before I set everything. I call this method, and when find some issue I want to finish current activity.

So this is snippet of my code:

```
private void PrepareData()
{
   try
   {
     //some code to prepare data here
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      Intent _startNewActivity = new Intent(this, ActivityB);
      this.StartActivity(_startNewActivity);
      this.Finish();
   }
}
```

and OnCreate like this

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ActivityA);

        PrepareData()

        toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "Activity A";
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

    }
```

Right Now, when app find error on PrepareData, intent is called and this.Finish() also called, but somehow app not finish Activity A immediately, it still set toolbar, and also call onResume.

I know there is activity lifecycle that onStop always called after onResume,But I want to know there is way to finish current activity immediately, without call next code?

Answer (score 1):

An activity always calls through the first lifecycle, even if you call finish, e.g. `onCreate --> onStart --> onResume`. Finish call is only scheduled to be performed after `onResume`. If your only issue is to prevent some code from executing in onResume, define a flag where you call `this.Finish()`, for instance `bool finishCalled = true;` and then to prevent the toolbar from setting the title, just wrap the code inside that bool with `if !(finishCalled)`.

That should do it.